# How can I conditionally insert an atrribute into an Angular template

Tags: angular, angular-template

I have an angular component.

Cutting out the unneeded bits it's mostly like.

```
@Component({
  template: `
<a class="link-button" [href]="href">Link Button</a>
  `
})
export class LinkButtonComponent {
    @Input() href: string | null = '';
}
```

I have a CSS selector for links to nowhere that greys them out:

```
a.button-link:not([href]) {
    background-color:#A7A9AB;
    border-color:#A7A9AB;
}
```

However, binding a null value gives href="null" and does not remove the attribute completely.

How can I conditionally bind an attribute so it doesn't show up on null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [attr.href] and the attribute will not be present in case of null value:

```
<a class="link-button" [attr.href]="href">Link Button</a>
```

Also, there is a typo in your code: *button-link* in CSS and *link-button* in HTML.